# Retrieving Laravel notification from database to blade

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

So i want to retrieve data from Notifications Table in laravel.

but what i am trying to do is showing notifications on public it means without an auth so it would show in here

[notification example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6jaZ.png)

if i do this it throws an error as undefined variable

```
@foreach( $notifications as $notif)
       lob {{ $notif->type }}
@endforeach
```

and then i tried to count the unreadNotifications but it throws an error of

> Trying to get property 'unreadNotifications' of non-object

what should i do in here? because after i search about this,
the solution always use `auth()->user()->notifications()` meanwhile what i am trying to do is showing notification in home.blade.php without any auth

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing because of the reason that there isn't any logged in user.

`auth()->user()` grabs the logged in user if there is any, otherwise it returns null.

What you have to do here is to get the user for which you want the notifications and then make call to notifications relation on it. For example: for grabbing notifications for user id 1, it would be `\App\User::find(1)->notifications`

Comment: yes thankyou, to completed this. i put on my controller to get the data and retrieve it with compact like usual 

$notifications = \App\User::find(1)->notifications;